# Include Native Prototype extensions into Node JS files

Tags: node.js

Consider the following two files for the sake of this example:

`src\helper\number.js`

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
  var s = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
  return s;
}

/*
(1).pad(3) // => "001"
(10).pad(3) // => "010"
(100).pad(3) // => "100"
*/
```

`src\helper\string.js`

```
String.prototype.toInt = function () {
    return parseInt(this);
};
```

Now, how can I get the rest of my JS code files, say `src\app.js`, to recognize and pick up these extension methods?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. This is what my `src\app.js` looks like:

```
// Include prototype extensions
require("./helper/number");
require("./helper/string");

console.log((10).pad(3));  // => "010"
console.log("10".toInt()); // => 10
```

The crux was to `require` the entire file without assigning to an object.